# jQuery Chosen plugin update issue after AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-chosen

I'm having an issue with the [jquery-chosen](/questions/tagged/jquery-chosen)plugin not applying to a control that is rebuilt by an [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax)call. I've looked around at other suggestions but don't seemed to have found a working answer.

I'm using [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)3.2.1 and [jquery-chosen](/questions/tagged/jquery-chosen)1.8.2

My [html](/questions/tagged/html)page is built in [php](/questions/tagged/php)and upon first output everything is fine
e.g:

```
<div id="leveldiv">
  <p>
    <label for="fk_level">Level</label>
    <select name="fk_level" class="chosen-select" id="fk_level" title="Level"><option value="0" selected = "selected">None</option>
    </select>
  </p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(".chosen-select").chosen({
    width: "200px"
  });
</script>
```

During runtime the **`fk_level` select** control is rebuilt using an [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax)call which calls the same [php](/questions/tagged/php)function used to initially draw the control. However the *chosen* functionality is lost and it just renders as a standard select box.

I've called both the `.trigger("liszt:updated")` method nd`.trigger("chosen:updated")` of the select control after replacing the containing `div` `innerHTML` but this doesn't seem to have any effect.

AJAX controlling code:

```
function buildLevel() {
  exID = window.document.forms[0].fk_examtype.value;
  sID = window.document.forms[0].fk_subject.value;

  str = "?action=1&exID=" + exID + "&sID=" + sID

  xmlhttp = getHTTPObject();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("leveldiv").innerHTML = this.responseText;
      $("#fk_level").trigger("liszt:updated");
      $("#fk_level").trigger("chosen:updated");
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "ajax.php" + str, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

And just for completeness, an example output from the [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax)call is:

```
<p>
  <label for="fk_level">Level</label>
  <select name="fk_level" id="fk_level" class="chosen-select" title="Level">
    <option value="0">None</option>
  </select>
</p>
```

I've been fiddling about with this for days now but just cant get the chosen plugin to apply to the control after the [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax)call. I've debugged this in Firefox Developer Edition and it's throwing no [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)errors.

Any help would be appreciated.

Mark.

Comment: You'll need to add: `$(function(){ });` in your jQuery code. Something like this: `$(function() {
  $("#fk_level").trigger("liszt:updated");
  $("#fk_level").trigger("chosen:updated");
});`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$("#fk_level").trigger("chosen:updated");` works if select box is not destroyed and values are changed. If select box is destroyed and recreated, you need to reactivate the plugin for the new select box.
So, in your AJAX controlling code, replace

```
$("#fk_level").trigger("liszt:updated");
$("#fk_level").trigger("chosen:updated");
```

with

```
$("#fk_level").chosen({
    width: "200px"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and I use the below sample example and worked fine with me

```js
$.ajax(
type: 'POST',
url: 'ApiUrl',
dataType: 'json',
async :false,
    success: function(resultList) {
        for (var item in resultList) {
            if (resultList.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
                $("#selectId").append("<option value=" +
                    resultList[item].value +
                    " id=" +
                    resultList[item].value +
                    ">" +
                    resultList[item].text +
                    "</option>");
            }


        }
        $("#selectId").trigger("liszt:updated");
        $("#selectId").trigger("chosen:updated");
    }
});
```